# Name for a semilattice-like structure

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

I have a partially ordered set, in which every pair of elements has an unique meet **or** an unique join (or both). Is there a name for a structure like this or have properties of structures like this been researched?

Comment: I don't think there is a name for such structure. If there is a context in which you're working and that type of structure is interesting and omnipresent, then perhaps you should come up with a name for it. There are some prefixes which have been used to refer to weaker versions of some property in some algebra. Some examples: quasi, demi, hemi, pre; of course there are also the perfixes sub and semi, but these already have a meaning (sub-lattice and semi-lattice).

Comment: Among the former four, I think that quasi is not adequate because your structure will not necessarily be a semi-lattice, so it'll be far from being a lattice. Perhaps demi-lattice or hemi-lattice would work, if those names were not taken yet.